# How to determine line selection in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, 2d, gdi+

Can anyone give me a simple logic to determine line selection?
if line selected. i want run some command.
The line is drawn on picturebox. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think u need something like this :-

```
If picturebox1.SelectionLength > 0 Then
    Dim firstLine As Integer = picturebox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(picturebox1.SelectionStart)
    Dim lastLine As Integer = picturebox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(picturebox1.SelectionStart + picturebox1.SelectionLength)
    For line As Integer = firstLine To lastLine
        Dim txt = picturebox1.Lines(line)
        'do something here or run some command as u want...
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a way to determine if some line was clicked or not.

A line is defined by two points. A straight is defined by a slope (m) and intercept (b).
First get the linear equation from the two points (aka the straight line that goes through both points).

Insert both points into a linear equation. You get two linear equations.

```
y1 = m * x1 + b
y2 = m * x2 + b
```

Solve for `b` and set equal.

```
y1 - m * x1 = y2 - m * x2
```

Solve for `m`

```
--> m = -(y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2)
```

Insert `m` into the first equation and solve for `b`

```
--> b = y1 - m * x1
```

Now you can, for a given X coordiante, e.g. the the x coordinate of a mouse click, determine which y-value your line has at this location:

```
Dim m, b As Double
GetSlopeIntercept(p1, p2, m, b) 'See above

Dim YLine as Double = m * MouseLocation.X + b
If Math.Abs(MouseLocation.Y - YLine) < 5 AndAlso _
   MouseLocation.X > Math.Min(p1.X, p2.X) AndAlso _
   MouseLocation.X < Math.Max(p1.X, p2.X) _
   Then MessageBox.Show("Line was clicked!")
```

In this example p1 and p2 are points describing the line.
Two avoid clicks beside the actual line but on the straight you need to check against the x-coordinates of your points as well. Adjust the `5` two define how exact the line has to be hit.

In practical you need some storage of the lines you have and check against each after a mouseclick and then apply more logic. Best would be to first define a line class

```
Public Class MyLine
    Public Property P1 As Point
    Public Property P2 as Point
    Public Property IsSelected As Boolean

    Public Sub New(P1 as Point, P2 as Point)
       Me.P1 = P1
       Me.P2 = P2
       IsSelected = False
    End Sub

    Public Sub DrawMe(ByRef g as Graphics, p As Pen)
       If IsSelected = False Then
           g.DrawLine(p, P1, P2)
       Else
           g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, P1, P2) 'Draw the line differently if it is selected
       EndIf
    End Sub

    Public Sub TrySelect(MouseLocation As Point)
        Dim m, b As Double
        GetSlopeIntercept(p1, p2, m, b) 'See above

        Dim YLine as Double = m * MouseLocation.X + b
        If Math.Abs(MouseLocation.Y - YLine) < 5 AndAlso _
           MouseLocation.X > Math.Min(p1.X, p2.X) AndAlso _
           MouseLocation.X < Math.Max(p1.X, p2.X) _
           Then Me.IsSelected = True Else Me.IsSelected = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Keep a collection of Line objects for drawing and processing.